# Taking Screenshot of Layout Android CardView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to capture one of my layout but getting black border in screenshot like below. How can I remove it ?
[image]

My code for taking screenshot is like below

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1= findViewById(R.id.quoteViewPager); 
        v1.getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: does the layout have margin?

Comment: I have used it as match_parent in layout...Thanks

Comment: margin can't be "match_parent". Please read my question.

Comment: oh sorry...there no any margin used in it :(

Comment: add your xml code @Rajubhai

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't get your code,

```
View v1= findViewById(R.id.quoteViewPager); 
v1.getRootView();
```

it should be :

```
v1 = v1.getRootView();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Its taking screenshot of full screen, I do not need take full screen.

Comment: Then I think you are picking wrong layout, or the layout you have chosen having margins.